# Why we need to mentions return type in get/post method while using Angular CRUD operation?

Tags: angular

```
 getCompanyInformation(id: number): Observable<BaseModel<CompanyInfoModel[]>> {
    return this.http.get<BaseModel<CompanyInfoModel[]>>(apiUrl + 'getcompanybyid/' + companyId)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log(`fetched company id=${companyId}`)),
        catchError(this.handleError<BaseModel<CompanyInfoModel[]>>(`getCompany id=${companyId}`))
      )
 }
```

From the above example i am trying to understand if we already have mentioned our return type as `:Observable<BaseModel<CompanyInfoModel[]>>` then why we need to mention again after get method `.get<BaseModel<CompanyInfoModel[]>>` if i remove this `<BaseModel<CompanyInfoModel[]>>` after .get() i am getting an error as Type `'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Obserable<BaseModel<CompanyInfoModel[]>>'`.

**BaseModel.ts**

```
export class BaseEntityModel<T> {
public entity: T[];
public status: number;
public message: string;
constructor(init?: Partial<BaseEntityModel<T>>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}
```

**CompanyModel.ts**

```
export class CompanyInformation {
companyID: number;
companyName: string;
description: string
constructor(init?: Partial<CompanyInformation>) {
   Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how typescript works. By default, `http.get` (with no parameter) returns an `Observable<Object>`. So If you declare your method's return type as `Observable<BaseModel<CompanyInfoModel[]>>`, Typescript will complain that what you declared as return type from your method does not match what the `http.get` call will return.

However, type infering should work the other way: If you use `http.get<BaseModel<CompanyInfoModel[]>>`, then you normally do not need to specify the return type for your method

```
 getCompanyInformation(id: number) {
    return this.http.get<BaseModel<CompanyInfoModel[]>>(apiUrl + 'getcompanybyid/' + companyId)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log(`fetched company id=${companyId}`)),
        catchError(this.handleError<BaseModel<CompanyInfoModel[]>>(`getCompany id=${companyId}`))
      )
 }
```

(Personnally I still like specifying the return type for readability)